# Compass css3 library not loading

Tags: css, compass-sass

I'm trying to `@import "compass/css3";` but it my phpstorm gives me an error. The error reads: "error style.scss (Line 36: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3".

Should I be including this css3 library as a framework or something?

Comment: Are you compiling your CSSs with compass executable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the approach stated here - http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/working-with-sass-and-scss-in-compass-projects.html